# Use fresco (facebook image library) to get scaled portion from the entire original image

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fresco

Basically i i have source image and i want to get scaled down region from the entire image. In the end i am expecting scaled down portion with same aspect ratio as that that of entire source image. Is it possible? If so please guide me what should i be looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into Fresco Documentation [here](http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing-rotating.html)

They say:

> To scale, simply specify the layout_width and layout_height of your SimpleDraweeView, as you would for any Android view. Then specify a scale type.

And for resizing you can make something like this:

```
Uri uri = "your uri";

int width = 50, height = 50;
ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
.setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(width, height))
.build();
PipelineDraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
.setOldController(mDraweeView.getController())
.setImageRequest(request)
.build();
mSimpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
```